# How to convert Python 3 script to executable file in Mac Catalina

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos-catalina

I really need an updated answer for this question. I want to convert the script into an executable that runs when I'd double click it. Some procedures, available online since last two-three years, are not working. I have just one script that's utilizing selenium and Geckodriver. The response I get against "which python3" is [image]

So kindly give answer if you've had yourself performed such a task in last few months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyInstaller didn't work in my case. Maybe it'd work on someone else's system. So, I went the simple "chmod" way and converted the python file into an executable. These were the steps:

1. On Terminal, I ran `which python3` and copy-pasted the result at the start of my python script, preceded with `#!`
2. Then I changed the extension of my python file to `.command`
3. On Terminal, I ran the command `chmod +x fileName.command` (755 instead of +x works too)

So, this is how I made my python file executable. There are other solutions too, but this one worked for me and is also simpler.

Comment: Isn't chmod for shell scripts?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PyInstaller running on a Mac to generate an executable.